# Suggest me phones with UHS-II support?

Tags: smartphones, tablet, microsd, sd-card

UHS-II(with 8 extra pins) supports much more speed than regular UHS-I microsd card, so I am going to buy a UHS-II microsd from (probably) Sandisk/Lexar. But I did not find any list of UHS-II supported phone/tablets.

So I want to know which smartphones/tablets support UHS-II.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### None.

At this moment there is no phone or tablet which supports UHS-II. Of course you can put UHS-II card in normal slot because it's backward compatible but there is many opinions that this cards are working worse than UHS-I cards when they are in UHS-I slots.

Comment: Some prowling around internet, makes it seem that (Oct 2016) there still are no mobile phones supporting UHS-II.

Comment: Some good UHS-I cards are Transcend W60 64G (U3, 95/60MB/s) and Lexar Professional 32G (95/45MB/s). Sandisk seemed both slower and more expensive than the previous two. I got a Toshiba Exceria 64G (U3) from aliexpress and likely too cheap; because either my testing, or the card, is flawed.

Comment: It's 2020, any updates?